# Adding function result to my html email php

Tags: php

I'm sure this is really simple but its driving me nuts!

```
<p>'.printHistory($result).' </p>
```

Above is a snippet of code from my html e-mail,and this is the function `printHistory`:

```
function printHistory($result){
    $hisNum=0;
    foreach ($result as $item){
        "<b><u>update Number </u></b>".$hisNum."<br/>";
        "<b>Time: </b>". $item['start_time']."<br/>";
        "<b>Date: </b>". $item['date']."<br/>";
        "<b>Comment: </b>". $item['comment']."<br/>";
        $hisNum=$hisNum+1;
    }
}
```

I receive no errors, but the text isn't printed to my e-mail. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to `return` the string, so no output is produced.

```
function printHistory($result){
    $hisNum=0;
    $string = "";
    foreach ($result as $item){
       $string .= "<b><u>update Number </u></b>".$hisNum."<br/>";
       $string .= "<b>Time: </b>". $item['start_time']."<br/>";
       $string .= "<b>Date: </b>". $item['date']."<br/>";
       $string .= "<b>Comment: </b>". $item['comment']."<br/>";
       $hisNum=$hisNum+1;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Perfect- it is always the simple things. Thank you. Will put this as correct when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo out the result:

```
function printHistory($result){
        $hisNum=0;
        foreach ($result as $item){
          echo "<b><u>update Number </u></b>".$hisNum."<br/>" 
              . "<b>Time: </b>". $item['start_time']."<br/>"
              . "<b>Date: </b>". $item['date']."<br/>"
              . "<b>Comment: </b>". $item['comment']."<br/>";
          $hisNum=$hisNum+1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Echoing it prints it to my html page, not the email.Thanks though.

Comment: Note that he's using `;` instead of `.` at the end of the lines as well, so it's 4 different strings instead of a single concatenated string.